# buying Monster Batteries w/ Parasitic Tentacles

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Say Player 1 has the Parasitic Tentacles card, which allows purchase of cards from other players for energy value. Player 2 has Monster Batteries, with some amount of energy on it (which was doubled and then recouped two energy per turn).... what happens to all the energy if that card is bought?
Does Player 1 get half of the energy still on the card, and the rest is returned to the bank? Does Player 2 get any of the energy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [boardgamegeek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1174750/parasitic-tentacles-and-monster-batteries) has a poster who appealed to iello's site and got this response

> "The energy cubes that were already on Monster Batteries go back into the bank pile, and the purchaser of Monster Batteries may then use the effect upon purchase."

So it seems like whatever cubes are left on there are simply lost to the bank, meaning the longer you can keep that card once you activate it, the better (before someone resets it with Parasitic Tentacles.